# Size Angular Material Slide Toggle (small, medium, large)

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular8

I want to increase the size of a Material Slide Toggle on a page of my Angular 8 project.
I have tried setting the size to large, like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle size="large" color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

However, changing the size from small, medium, and large changes nothing. It remains the same size of the screen. I've also tried adding a style to the component like this:

```
mat-slide-toggle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

But that doesn't change the the size of the visible component, but it does increase the div the component is in.

**How do I change the size of the Material Slide Toggle Component?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens that because you're styling wrapper of this component. You need to style specific classes of that component which are .mat-slide-toggler-bar and .mat-slide-toggle-thumb with ::ng-deep selector if your styles is encapsulated. Here is an example which will get you started to playing with increasing size of toggler:

```
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  height: 7px;
  width: 28px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    transform: translate3d(18px,0,0) !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I wasn't able to fully apply this. I couldn't affect the translatate3d properly to reflect the changes in size. But you gave me a good starting point. If you have any more suggestions here my bitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slidetoggle

Comment: Can you share code with me so I could try to help you out with it?

Comment: Yeah, I have a bitz here, you should be able to edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slidetoggle

Comment: Okay, so I've found the problem why translate property doesn't apply for you. You need to nest CSS selector .difSized.mat-slide-toggle.-mat.checked because .difSized element has those classes inside, not as child elements. Here is the edited stackblitz for further investigation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slidetoggle-rjgs2n 

You'll still need to explore how to fix other styling properties, however, now you can style everything inside toggler.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a bunch, this will work great! I hope material adds a size property in the future to make this way simplier.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you out :) And... totally agree with you! Changing such simple things in Material requires a lot of tweaks which are annoying and time confusing.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but isn't ::ng-deep being deprecated? https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

One solution to avoid using ::ng-deep would be to make sure the above code is in a global style file, remove all ::ng-deep, and preface each selector with 'mat-slide-toggle.mat-slide-toggle'. That will override the current mat-slide-toggle style as it is more specific.

Answer (score 18):

I think the easiest solution is to simply use scale() on .mat-slide-toggle. This is how I did it and it worked perfectly:

```
.mat-slide-toggle {
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

This will probably shift the slider to the right. To fix it:

```
 .mat-slide-toggle {
        transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-10px); //adjust the pixels to your scale size i
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the selected answer, you need to style the internal classes of mat-slide-toggle (mat-slide-toggle-bar, mat-slide-toggle-thumb, etc). However, /deep/ and ::ng-deep are deprecated, so you shouldn't be using those. One option is to set global styling that is more specific than the default styling on the component. So in a global style file, you could do something like this:

```
mat-slide-toggle.mat-slide-toggle .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 26px;
}

mat-slide-toggle.mat-slide-toggle .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

//...etc
```

Combining the component name and class name gives more specificity than the mat-slide-toggle default styling, so it overrides it.

References:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-overlay-components
- https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: You can use `ng-deep` now by using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none` in the `@Component` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

just set your favorite size in this code:

```
::ng-deep {
 .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
 }
 .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
 }

.mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  width: 42px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

}